# How to setup multiple class in my case

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-class

I am trying to setup an `ng-class` in my app

I have something like this

```
$scope.myClass = 'class-A';
```

do something here…

```
$scope.myClass ='class-B';
```

do something here

```
$scope.myClass ='class-C';
```

html

```
<div ng-class="{myClass}"></div>
```

The above codes work. The problem is when I add additional one, it doesn't work anymore.

```
<div ng-class="{myClass, 'class-cool':openDialog}"></div>
```

I am getting

```
Token ',' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 15 of the expression
```

They work if I use them separately but not together. Can anyone help me about the issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: cant you put `$scope.myClass` inside `class` not in `ng-class`, as `class="{{ myClass }}"`

Comment: but then it won't update dynamically to class-B or class-C

Comment: why not ? did u check ?

Comment: Because that's how Angular works and yes. I check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this. `myClass` will always be set since `true` will always be true.

```
<div ng-class="{myClass:true, 'class-cool':openDialog}"></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't have error anymore but the class doesn't take effect from myClass +1

Comment: Are both classes set? Or what's the problem? @BonJon